# Customer cus_* already has the maximum number of payment methods attached

Tags: stripe-payments

Almost never worked with a stripe.
Once I solved the problem with payment and that's it.

There is a site on which the user orders some stuff. Well, for payment - he attaches his card. Where the Stripe error is popping up with the text: "Customer cus_* already has the maximum number of payment methods attached."

why is this happening? Is there a maximum reached and what is it? how can i get rid of this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are seeing this error message, `maximum number of payment methods attached` as there is a limit on how many payment methods can be attached to a specific customer. There are limits for cards and for sources.

To correct this, you can [remove](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/detach) some of the existing payment methods from that customer. Moving forward, you can periodically detach payment methods that are older or won't need to be used again in your integration.

Comment: Hi! Sorry for bothering you. Is there any specifit limitation for customer? Because, I saw the customer has 10 payment methods. And what's the endpoint to figure out how many there  are payemnts in sources?